# Is there a way to access graphql endpoint from rest api class using java?

Tags: java, neo4j, graphiql

Can we create and execute the graphql queries from POJO class? I have gone through multiple links but unable to find any where we can set the URL in java class to access graphql endpoint. I have added graphql plugin to neo4j community edition.

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you want to achieve in your POJO classes ?

Comment: hi @logisima. I do not have any java class written. I have only tried with bolt driver till now which is returning the result in tabular format and i have to write codes explicitly to extract data. But when we query using graphiql, it returns the result with json format. Is there a way to create graphiql query and format response in a java class ?

Comment: What you need is a graphql java client like This https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/